# Why isn't no-repeat working for these background images and how do I get the list text to not sit on top of the image?

Tags: css, html-lists, background-image

UPDATE EDIT. Because part of this problem is still not solved. 
Moving the background no-repeat fixed the image repetition problem but the the list item text is still positioned on top of the background image as it was before. It also has an extra tick to the left of the background image as it did before. See new screen capture.

[image: list text positioned over background list item image]

I have modified my original code and tried many ways to adjust the margins and padding to try to fix the position of the background image but nothing I have tried works.

Here is the current CSS:

```
ul.follow-background {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.follow {
    background: no-repeat left 16px; /** fixed vertical position **/
    padding: 0 0.6em 0 0;
}

.follow-background .follow a::before {
    content: '';
    list-style: none outside !important;
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 1em;
    padding: 0 0 0 0.6em;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right:20px;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.follow.facebookicon {
    background-image: url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon-16x16.png')
}

.follow.flickricon {
    background-image: url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/fluid-flickr-logo-16x16.png');
}

.follow.linkedinicon {
    background-image: url('http://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/linkedin-icon-16x16.png');
}

.follow.pinteresticon {
    background-image: url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/pinterest-logo-16x16.png');
}

.follow.rssicon {
    background-image: url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/rss-logo-blue-bullet-16x16.png');
}

.follow.twittericon {
    background-image: url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/twitter.gif');
}
```

THE HTML is the same as before:

```
<p>Follow us on our social media connections:</p>
<ul class="follow-background">
<li class="follow facebookicon"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/baeeorg" rel="nofollow">Facebook</a></li>
<li class="follow flickricon"><a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/baee/" rel="nofollow">Flickr Photo Albums</a></li>
<li class="follow pinteresticon"><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/baee0196/" rel="nofollow">Pinterest</a></li>
<li class="follow twittericon"><a href="https://twitter.com/BaeeArtists" rel="nofollow">Twitter</a></li>
<li class="follow rssicon"><a href="https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/news/" rel="nofollow">News Announcements (subscribe to get our latest posts)</a></li>
</ul>
```

END EDIT UPDATE
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: It is reproducible in a variety of browsers. Look at it in Opera. Each browser handles it differently. Need to find a way to make it consistent in all browsers.

Comment: It's reproducible but caused by a **TYPO**

Comment: What is the typo? Everything looks spelled correctly to me.

Comment: This problem is reproducible in five different browsers. Saying it is on hold for a typo, isn't clear. Please point out the typo. I have carefully inspected the code and I didn't find a misspelled word, a missing bracket, or a missing  semicolon. I've run the code through a CSS editor and no typo was indicated.

Comment: You're missing the point. The "typo" is that you put the property on the **wrong element**.

Comment: To me a "typo" is a mistake  in typing. Is the property still on the wrong element in the revised code? I moved it to where the first answer said it should go but the margins are still wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your updated question here is a new answer. Although your method will technically work by simply adding some `left padding` to your anchor and adding a `list-style:none;` to your `.follow` class I thought it best to provide a new solution that you can reuse in the future.

```css
.follow {
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
}
.follow:before {
  content:'';
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  top:7px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.facebookicon:before{
  background-image:url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/facebook-icon-16x16.png');
}
.flickricon:before {
   background-image:url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/fluid-flickr-logo-16x16.png');
}
.pinteresticon:before {
   background-image:url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/pinterest-logo-16x16.png');
}
.twittericon:before {
   background-image:url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/twitter.gif');
}
.rssicon:before {
   background-image:url('https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/wp-content/uploads/rss-logo-blue-bullet-16x16.png');
}
```

```html
<ul class='follow-background'>
  <li class='follow facebookicon'><a href='#' title='' rel='nofollow'>Facebook</a></li>
   <li class='follow flickricon'><a href='#' title='' rel='nofollow'>Flickr Photo Albums</a></li>
   <li class='follow pinteresticon'><a href='#' title='' rel='nofollow'>Pinterest</a></li>
   <li class='follow twittericon'><a href='#' title='' rel='nofollow'>Twitter</a></li>
   <li class='follow rssicon'><a href='#' title='' rel='nofollow'>News Announcments ( subscribe to get our latest posts ) </a></li>
  
</ul>
```

### Left the previous answer as it was still relevant

You are adding `background: no-repeat left 7px;` on the container & Psuedo class but as the background is being defined on `.follow` it won't inherit the no-repeat property so basically add

```
.follow {
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That worked for the Safari browser but I just checked my other test browsers and it is till repeating.

Comment: I have just added the code you provided in your question into a codepen and tested in various browsers it seems to have worked for me, perhaps your being served a cached version did you try doing a full refresh?  if you have a live URL available i'll take a look.

Comment: Live URL is https://www.botanical-art.baeecorp.org/about-us/#more-12

Comment: Just looked at the URL you provided and it appears there is no background repeating you just need to add some left padding to your anchor tag so the background image isn't overlapping the text.

Comment: I've tried several things to try to make the image not sit on top of the list item text but nothing I've tried works I will edit the question to show what I have now. The weird thing is that it shows with the image on the text in all browsers but in Firefox there is also an extra tick mark to the left of the image. Don't know what is causing that.

Comment: Thank you. Your snippit shows your code works but for some reason it doesn't work when I plug it into my stylesheet. I've even put it as the very last thing in the stylesheet to avoid other styles affecting it.  I'm giving up and will do the list without background images. Too inconsistent in various browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the rule to the `::before` pseudo selector, which is a separate element that is the first child of its parent.

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an element with the content property. It is inline by default.

[MDN ::before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)

You need to add your background rule to the `.follow` class. You could also consider using [list-style-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image).

Comment: For a background image, it needs to be list-style: none.